# How can I toggle the visibility of a table-row without messing up the styling for the odd rows?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, html-table, css-selectors

A goodmorning fellow StackOverflow users,

I have created a visibility toggle for all of the empty rows / equal values in a table. It sets the display property to "none", of course that would mean that it still exists in the DOM, but how can I ignore these rows in this given scenario?

This makes it so that two (odd) rows will be listed underneath eachother which messes up with the styling.

Any ideas on how I can fix this up? I was thinking of adding a :not selector to the CSS, but I couldn't get it to work myself.

**Method:**

```
    showEmptyRows() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('perfect-match')

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('perfect-match');
            if (elements[i].style.display === "none") {
                elements[i].style.display = "table-row";
                elements[i].classList.remove("hide");
            } else {
                elements[i].style.display = "none";
                elements[i].classList.add("hide");
            }
        }
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
.merge-table > tbody > tr:not(.hide):nth-of-type(odd) > * {
    --bs-table-accent-bg: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a text-based [mcve]

Comment: _"of course that would mean that it still exists in the DOM"_ - exactly, and because :nth-of selectors are based on the DOM structure, you simply _can't_ do it using those. You would need to either actually remove the row from the DOM (for example by appending it to another table, which you made invisible - then you could simply "restore" it afterwards, by inserting it in the correct position of the original table again) - or you will have to use classes for your odd/even styling, and then update those classes on all rows, after you have hidden or re-shown one.

Comment: Ye I was thinking of maybe using a counter in my for-loop to determine the index of a row.